# How to delete character from a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in python and i started to learn python 3 without learning python 2. I'm trying to apply the `string.translate()` function which I've learnt  that is not supported in python 3.

```
from string import maketrans


intab = "0123456789"
outtab = ""
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)
str = "p1y2t3h4o5n6"
print(str.translate(trantab))
```

running it gives following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
from string import maketrans
ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans'
```

I intend to get the output as `python`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer to the question

Don't use the name `str` for your string variable. It will mask the built-in `str`:

```
intab = "0123456789"
outtab = intab[::-1]
trantab = str.maketrans(intab, outtab)
mystring = "p1y2t3h4o5n6"
print(mystring.translate(trantab))
```

Output:

```
p8y7t6h5o4n3
```

Your `intab` and `outtab` must have the same length. Most functions from `string` in Python 2 became methods of `str` for a while in Python 2 and were dropped as functions from `string` in Python 3. So use `str.maketrans()`.

## Solving the problem

If want to remove characters from a string you can do:

```
remove = set("0123456789")
mystring = "p1y2t3h4o5n6"
print(''.join(x for x in mystring if x not in remove))
```

Output:

```
python
```

If you want to remove numbers you can also do:

```
print(''.join(x for x in mystring if not x.isdigit()))
```

Output:

```
python
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for the explanation. 
But my problem still leaves me with the ValueEror

Comment: Did your my answer: *Your `intab` and `outtab` must have the same length.*

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) static method instead (note that you don't need to import it).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in from Python 3.x you need to use the static method [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans). That being said the `intab` and `outtab` must have equal length.

```
>>> str = "p1y2t3h4o5n6"
>>> intab = "0123456789"
>>> outtab = " "
>>> trantab = str.maketrans(intab, outtab * len(intab))
>>> print(mystring.translate(trantab).replace(" ", ""))
python
```

But you can also do this using regular expression

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[0-9]', '', mystring)
'python'
```